# prepareForSegue not being called from UITableView in a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView. The table view contains a custom UITableViewCell. The custom cell was built in interface builder and has a nib. In my main storyboard, I dragged a segue from the custom table view cell to the destination view controller. I set up the bare bones essentials in prepareForSegue, set a break point, but it never gets called.

I'm not that accustomed to using a UITableView in a view controller. I usually use a UITableViewController, but requirements dictate using the table view in a view controller. My initial assumptions is that most methods of doing things would be nearly identical, but I'm finding that not to be the case.

I tried setting the segue from the view controller itself and using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and though it worked, the transition to the destination view controller was jerky.

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing in order to cause the prepareForSegue method to fire?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    GaugeViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    [destination setGaugeID:@"1"];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?

Comment: I don't have code to post for this situation. I have created the segue in IB and set a breakpoint in prepareForSegue and it's not called

Comment: You must have some code somewhere in your project since you're calling `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: see edits. Like I said, not much to show. Really just trying to figure out why this method won't fire

Comment: Are you trying to do a push segue? If so, is your controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Answer (score -1):

You need to refer to the identity of the segue in the Storyboard, something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    GaugeViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"]) {
       NSLog(@"prepareForSegue called");
       [destination setGaugeID:@"1"];
    }else {
       // do something else
    }

}
```

Also don't forget to set the Identifier in the Storyboard.

[image]

Remember that push segues are used with Navigation Controllers and a modal segue can be dragged from view controller to view controller.

Comment: I agree. Currently, however, code never reaches prepareForSegue so I'm trying to just reach a breakpoint in that method before moving on

Comment: @Pheepster Did you name the Segue Identifier in the Storyboard?

Comment: No, you don't actually need to refer to the identifier. It's often good practice to do so, and would be necessary if you have more than one segue connected to this controller. It wouldn't cause the problem the OP is seeing.